# Changing the number of grids on orientation change in jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, orientation-changes

I am trying to change number of grids on orientation is landscape from 2 to 3 grids how can I achieve this?

Comment: are you solved this one.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, we cant use **window.orientation** to definitely recognize **portrait** or **landscape** orientation, because every device will give different results. Read more about it here: http://www.matthewgifford.com/2011/12/22/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/

So, to achieve this we need to use classic orientation detection function. If window height is bigger then window width the we have a portrait or in any other case we have a landscape orientation.

I made you a working example of your question. Unfortunately I cant create you a jsFiddle example because it wont detect **orientationchange** event. To test code below, just copy it into an empty html file.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <style>
        .ui-block-a {
            background: red;
        }

        .ui-block-b {
            background: green;      
        }

        .ui-block-c {
            background: blue;       
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script>    

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
            detectOrientationMode();
        }); 

        $(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
            detectOrientationMode();
        });     

        function detectOrientationMode() {
            if($(window).height() > $(window).width()) {
                $('#custom-grid .ui-block-c').css('display','none');            
                $('#custom-grid').removeClass('ui-grid-b').addClass('ui-grid-a');
            } else {
                $('#custom-grid .ui-block-c').css('display','block');           
                $('#custom-grid').removeClass('ui-grid-a').addClass('ui-grid-b');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-a" id="custom-grid">
                <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your answer seems good but i need the "ui-block-c" in next row not hide. How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the three grids present and addClass('hidden') or removeClass('hidden') as appropriate, and assign display: none to the class hidden in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and Without better advice I simply found a workaround:

I just use the jquery mobile orientation change detection to switch between 2 different div (data-role page) duplicating my content with different layouts.